# Throwing StackUnderFlowException - how to do it? Is it costly?

Tags: java, exception, stack

I have a Stack that could potentially be empty.  I want to check that it is empty, and if it is I want to throw a `StackUnderFlowException`:

```
if(myStack.empty()) {
   throw new StackUnderFlowException("Some error message");
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this efficient?  I know you're not meant to use Exceptions for flow control.. I don't think I am because I'm explicitly checking that the stack is empty?
2. How do I import the `StackUnderFlowException` class because I get this error at the moment:

   The method foo(String) from the type PriceHolder refers to the missing type StackUnderFlowException

Many thanks.

Comment: did you mean `myStack.empty()` ?

Comment: Sorry... it's a `HashTable` of `Stack`s.  I'll get rid of the `HashTable` stuff from the question because it's irrelevant.

Comment: There is no standard StackUnderflowException. It could come from a library you're using, but if you don't say which and show your code, we can't tell. The standard exception to use would be `java.util.EmptyStackException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this efficient?

Certainly. It should never happen except in code with bugs, and who cares how efficient code is that doesn't execute correctly?

> I know you're not meant to use Exceptions for flow control.

Whatever that means. The trouble with this gnomic *pronunciamento* is that exceptions *are* a form of flow control. Don't get too hung up about received opinions in this business. Many of them are ephemeral, and many more are worthless. In this case throwing an exception is entirely plausible. Better in this case than using an out-of-band return value, and sometimes there *aren't* any out-of-band return values.

> I don't think I am because I'm explicitly checking that the stack is empty?

I don't understand the relevance of this sentence.

> How do I import the StackUnderFlowException class

*What* `StackUnderflowException` class? There isn't one in the JDK. Maye you have to *write* it?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually speaking, you use flow control for things you expect to happen, and exceptions for things that shouldn't happen. In most libraries I've seen (including the standard Java libraries) trying to access a non-existent container element is considered a programming error, and it's often signaled using an exception or a similar mechanism.

As for #2, you'll need to determine the package that StackUnderFlowException is in. If you need help with that, please specify which StackUnderFlowException you're using.